# JNI error on Mac OS X 10.4.11... dyld: Symbol not found: _objc_setProperty

Tags: java, objective-c, cocoa, gcc, java-native-interface

I have a problem with some JNI code.
I'm getting the following error printed in the console from a OS X 10.4.11 (PPC) machine (it works fine on newer versions of OS X 10.5+)

```
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _objc_setProperty
  Referenced from: /Path/to/my/lib/libMylib32.jnilib
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib

dyld: Symbol not found: _objc_setProperty
  Referenced from: /Path/to/my/lib/libMylib32.jnilib
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
```

I have another jnilib which works fine that runs before this one in the program. The error seems to be saying I'm missing some core objective c "stuff". The other jnilib which is working on 10.4.11 uses just 1 .m file and doesn't use objective c properties (it uses NSMutableArray, NSDictionary, CFPreferences and so on). The one which doesn't work on 10.4.11 is more complex makes use of some objective c classes with properites I wrote.

Maybe I'm not compiling my code correctly or maybe properties aren't supported?

I have a shell script which compiles the jnilib. It's practically the same as the one which works as far as I can tell. I have another section for compiling the 64 bit jnilib above this in the script but the 32 bit one is being used for 10.4.11.

```
COCOA_HEADERS=/System/Library/Frameworks/Cocoa.framework/Headers
BITS=32
JAVA_HEADERS=/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.5/Headers
MAC_SDK=/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.4u.sdk
CFLAGS="-fPIC -arch i386 -arch ppc"
LIB_NAME=${LIB_PREFIX}${BITS}.jnilib
MAC_LIB_OUTPUT=/path/to/my/output/folder/${LIB_NAME}
DYLIB_ARCH="-arch i386 -arch ppc"

rm *.o
#Compile for 1.5 32bit Java
gcc -v -std=gnu99 -c ${CFLAGS} -isysroot ${MAC_SDK} -I${JAVA_HEADERS} -I${COCOA_HEADERS} ${SOURCE_FILES}
# Make the library file from the object files (*.o)
gcc -v -dynamiclib -o ${MAC_LIB_OUTPUT} *.o  -framework JavaVM -framework Cocoa ${DYLIB_ARCH}
```

I appreciate your answers and ideas on how to debug this one.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Properties are a new Objective-C 2 feature [Apple site](http://developer.apple.com/leopard/overview/objectivec2.html) and that only runs on OSX 10.5 and above. Thus I suspect the C code will only run on 10.5

You will have to write the C code targeting older versions of OSX. For details see [Apple docs](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/cross_development/Introduction/Introduction.html) This includes non Xcode ways

Answer (score 1):

Use Xcode. It supports Java, and it's designed to handle things like supporting old versions of Mac OS X. In Xcode, you would set your `SDKROOT` to macosx10.4u (Mac OS X, 10.4 with universal binary support) and `MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET` to 10.4, and Xcode will tell the linker where to get the right versions of the frameworks.

If you insist on building with a shell script, then you'll need to do that yourself. You're currently using the system versions.

Comment: But I'll still have to convert to not use objective c properties right? So, it just uses Objective C 1.0 features for pre leopard support like Mark is saying? Also, are you talking about using the JNI template from XCode? I tried using the JNI template but I found it a bit cumbersome since I didn't really need/want to use javah and I couldn't figure out how to customize the project/settings. I was able to find some examples of Mac JNI in open source projects and the ones I looked at use make or shell scripts so that's what I ended up doing. I still write the code in XCode.

Comment: “But I'll still have to convert to not use objective c properties right? So, it just uses Objective C 1.0 features for pre leopard support like Mark is saying?” Right; you can't use anything from Objective-C 2.0 on Tiger.

Comment: “I still write the code in XCode.” Using Xcode as only a text editor doesn't get you the conveniences of its build system.

Comment: I agree and think it would be better if I could setup the build from XCode (if I could figure it out) but for now your suggestion about MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.4 was helpful. GCC prints warnings about the use of properties like this MenuActionTarget.h:17: warning: Mac OS X version 10.5 or later is needed for use of property. Thanks.